# A rude equivalent to a "TV box" term

Tags: terminology, phrase-requests

I am looking for an American English term for a "TV box" as a source of zombification and brain killing. Maybe "boob tube" is the right one? The shorter, the better.

Comment: I'll note that all of the suggested terms -- *idiot box, google box, boob tube* -- can be considered *informal* or even *slang*, but I would by no means call them *rude*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Idiot box](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idiot+box)** or **[goggle box](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/goggle+box)**.

Both terms have been around since the [fifties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dul6j.png).

[image: idiot and goggle box]

Alternatively, **brain rotter** is nicely descriptive.

Comment: It's Idiot box.

Comment: Just curios, where can I get diagrams like yours for other words?

Comment: From the [Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams). It's a lot of fun but you need to be careful with some of the results due to dodgy metadata.

Answer (score 6):

*Boob tube* is the way to go:

> **boob tube**, *noun*. Etymology: boob + tube (television); from the notion that television programming is foolish or is viewed by foolish
>   people : TELEVISION ; especially : a television set

*Boob tube* also enjoys wider currency than *idiot box*, at least according to this Ngram:

[image]

Comment: A boob tube is also a piece of clothing for females, similar to a crop top but usually Lycra or similarly stretch material.

Comment: I usually see those referred to as _tube tops_.

Comment: I suspect that a good half of those Google hits are for the clothing. *Tube top* is what they're called if you're offended by the word *boob* for breasts.

Comment: @slim _Boob tube_ is apparently a Briticism for _tube top_; none of the 50 results for _boob tube_ in [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) refer to clothing. (And I've heard little old church ladies use the term _boob tube_, so apparently it's not that offensive in that context.)

Comment: I'm British and I've never heard the alternative term "tube top", nor heard the phrase "boob tube" applied to anything *other* than the top.

Answer (score 3):

I rather like "glass teat", although it's not as popular as the others.

Answer (score 1):

[The opium of the people?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opium_of_the_people)  ;)

Comment: ... is religion, per the March quote. If you want to subvert that and make it TV, you need to signal it to your readers somehow.

Comment: @slim ... whence the wink. But I take your point: I should save my more frivolous answers for the comments.

Comment: Marx not March. Phone typo. Doh.